# The leading principal minors of any orthogonal matrix is less than 2.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am curious that if there exists the following conclusion:

> The leading principal minors of any orthogonal matrix is less than 2.

I don't know how to prove or disprove it, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer I posted yesterday, Xin?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks! I got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Hadamard's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality) says the determinant of a matrix is at most the product of the lengths of its columns, considered as vectors. The columns of an orthogonal matrix all have length one, so the columns of any minor have length at most one, so the product is at most one, so the determinant is at most one. Since one is less than two, we win.